# How to reference top-level parameters in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use top level parameters and then, at the operation level,use a $ref to refer to the definition that was declared at the top level object.

Here is what the YAML looks like but when I try this I get an empty parameter displayed. Anyone know the correct syntax for this?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.1.0
  title: Customer API
parameters:
  index:
    name: index
    in: query
    description: Specifies the offset of the first item to be returned. The default value is 0, which starts at the beginning.
    type: integer
    default: 0
    minimum: 0
paths:
  /customers:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/index'
      responses:
        200:
          description:  List all customers
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Customers'
definitions:
  Customer:
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int32
  Customers:
    properties:
      startIndex:
        type: integer
      itemsPerPage:
        type: integer
      totalResults:
        type: integer
      entries:
        type: array
        $ref: Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

The support for this has yet to be implemented in swagger-ui. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/621.